# Using version 1.x.x for android public beta app without having a production app

Tags: android, google-play

I wish to release a new app as public beta for Android and production for iOS. I wish to have the same version numbers for both. But, iOS doesn't allow version less than 1.0.0 for production, correct me if I am wrong.

So can I use version 1.x.x for an android public beta app?

Is there any restrictions in Google play to use appropriate version numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever versionName you want. The only thing that matters is the versionCodes have to increment.  You can't upload a new APK with a matching or lower version code.

> The versionName has no purpose other than to be displayed to users.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reference. I was confused because of not having a production app on android, which isn't discussed else where.

Answer (score 0):

On gradle you set "versionCode" with an integer, this integer must be necessarily superior to the previous version. check play console for help about alpha-beta versionCode hierarchies.

on the same gradle you set "versionName" string, the info that your apps users will see, this is a free textfield, you can use "1.x.x" or "1.xx.xx_beta"

productFlavors allows free texfields too

check the "app info" about apps instaled on your device and compare styles